# UINavigationItem is not shown in my ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, ios6.1

I'm writing a simple app in iOS using Xcode, I'm trying to load another `ViewController` as a modal. The origin `HomeScreenViewController` (inherits from `UIViewController`) where I'm loading the modal is originated with the project's Storyboard.
Then, as a response to a button pressed event, I'm loading this modal like this:

```c
-(IBAction)onAddButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    MyAnotherViewController *vc = [[MyAnotherViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The class `MyAnotherViewController` is not represented in the Storyborad since its a simple class to show a navigation bar and a text field. The code is (partial code, the rest is Xcode auto-generated methods):

```c
@implementation MyAnotherViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Example"];
    [self.view addSubview:[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]];
}
@end
```

The problem is (also can be seen in the attached image) that the `navigationItem` is not shown for some reason.
I also validated that `self.navigationItem` is not `nil` and it is not. Even more, I can see in debug mode that the title is actually set to "Example".

[image: As can be seen in the screenshot, the UITextView captures the entire screen]

Your help is well appreciated,
Cheers...

Comment: Hi, when we load view controller as model then navigation bar is hide every time and you need to manage it via adding tool bar and bar button item.

Comment: thanks for your note :) also Vinzzz below gave me the exact answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UINavigationItem` property of a UIViewController is only used when the ViewController is inside a `UINavigationController`, so :

```
-(IBAction)onAddButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    MyAnotherViewController *vc = [[MyAnotherViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navCtl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:vc];
    [self presentViewController:navCtl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyAnotherViewController` is not a subclass of `UINavigationController`, or if you have not manually add an `UINavigationItem`, `UIViewController` cannot show a navigation item. Maybe you can try to wrap the `MyAnotherViewController` with an `UINavigationController`.

```
// Assume you have adopted ARC
-(IBAction)onAddButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    MyAnotherViewController *vc = [[MyAnotherViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And in your `-viewDidLoad` of `MyAnotherViewController`, you just need to do this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Example";
    /*
     * Your other code
     */
}
```